# GreenDao how to update table by other column (not the primary key id)?

Tags: android, sql, greendao

I know I can use these code to update the table, but it use the primary key id for comparison.

```java
DaoSession daoSession = ((App) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
StudentDao studentDao = daoSession.getStudentDao();
studentDao.update(studentBean);   //update by id
```

But sometimes, I need to use other column to update the table, it maybe like:

```
UPDATE STUDENT_TABLE SET ADDRESS = 'Texas' WHERE NAME = 'David';
```

How to implement the above sql statement with greendao?

Comment: Refere to [this](https://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/current/org/greenrobot/greendao/AbstractDao.html#method.summary). `queryRaw` could be used in this case

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni It seems to me that the `queryRaw` is used to SELECT, not to UPDATE

Comment: You can run any raw queries I think, use the update query you have there and check.